# Find frequency of keys of dictionary from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am supposed to find out the frequencies of different keys in a list of dictionaries.

For example:

Input list of dictionaries:

```
[{'p1': 'val1', 'p2': 'val2', 'p3': 'val3', 'p4': 'val4'},
 {'p1': 'val5', 'p7': 'val6', 'p3': 'val7'},
 {'p1': 'val8', 'p2': 'val9', 'p9': 'val10', 'p7': 'val11'}]
```

Output format: Dictionary with key as keys seen in input dictionary, and values as a list containing frequency and list of values as seen in input. The order of keys in output does not matter.

Output:

```
{'p1': [3, ['val1', 'val5', 'val8']],
 'p2': [2, ['val2', 'val9']],
 'p3': [2, ['val3', 'val7']],
 'p4': [1, ['val4']],
 'p7': [2, ['val6', 'val11']],
 'p9': [1, ['val10']]
}
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?
Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am new to python, so can't think of anything except loops, but I am looking for a more efficient way, or, using loops in a more efficient manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straightforward way of getting the desired output:

```
result = {}
for d in list_of_dicts:
    for k, v in d.items():
        result.setdefault(k, [0, []])
        result[k][0] += 1
        result[k][1].append(v)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it's simpler than mine!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution (`lst` is your original input):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct = defaultdict(lambda: [0, []])
for d in lst:
    for key, value in d.items():
        dct[key][1].append(value)
        dct[key][0] += 1
dct = dict(dct)
```

The result contained in `dct`:

```
{'p1': [3, ['val1', 'val5', 'val8']],
 'p2': [2, ['val2', 'val9']],
 'p3': [2, ['val3', 'val7']],
 'p4': [1, ['val4']],
 'p7': [2, ['val6', 'val11']],
 'p9': [1, ['val10']]}
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that a large portion of your recent contributions on this site are on off-topic questions that end up getting closed. If I recall correctly, I've even see you suggest other members to _not_ answer such questions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399850/what-is-the-appropriate-course-of-action-towards-a-user-that-is-consistently-ans

Comment: @NicolasGervais Thanks for your feedback. I don't think this question should be "more focused", as it has been tagged. The input and the expected output were both given by the OP. It's pretty clear what the result should be, I think the question is perfectly focused. However, thanks for your feedback, I'm going to review again the guidelines that you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using `pandas`

```py
import pandas as pd

#Your dataset
d1 = [
    {'p1': 'val1', 'p2': 'val2', 'p3': 'val3', 'p4': 'val4'},
    {'p1': 'val5', 'p7': 'val6', 'p3': 'val7'},
    {'p1': 'val8', 'p2': 'val9', 'p9': 'val10', 'p7': 'val11'}]

#Read the dataset into a dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

myDict = dict()
#Iterate over the columns and add to a dictionary the elaborated values removing the nan
for label, content in df1.iteritems():
    myContent = [content for content in content if str(content) != 'nan']
    myDict[label] = [len(myContent), myContent]

print myDict
```

Result:

`{'p2': [2, ['val2', 'val9']], 'p3': [2, ['val3', 'val7']], 'p1': [3, ['val1', 'val5', 'val8']], 'p7': [2, ['val6', 'val11']], 'p4': [1, ['val4']], 'p9': [1, ['val10']]}`